# How to run Google Datalab locally?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, docker-toolbox

How do I run Datalab locally when it requires Docker (and Docker Toolbox is not supported as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local)? The Docker website says Docker requires Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise 64-bit, and most corporate environments don't run Windows 10.

Comment: docker-toolbox is really just a way to get a virtual machine with docker running quickly. In all likelihood, it may work just fine, but the google cloud project may not want to write the documentation for it nor go to the trouble of answering community questions for more than one docker installation method.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is highly preferred over Docker Toolbox, as its a simpler, self-contained installation, with simpler configuration (since you don't have additional virtualization software to deal with, as you do with Docker Toolbox - namely boot2docker and its underlying functionality). However if you have a setup to run docker on your end, you should theoretically be able to use that for running the Datalab docker container by adapting the instructions.

You do have the option of running everything on a GCE VM.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, what I found more comfrotable in the end is to [install Ubuntu on Virtual Box](http://www.beopensource.com/2016/05/how-to-install-Ubuntu-1604-LTS-in-Virtual-Box-VmWare.html). This is free and fairly easy, and from the virtual machine you can use all the Docker and the Google guide to run Datalab locally.